# if cell a matches value a and cell c matches value c, then input cell b

Tags: excel-formula

Here's a picture as reference:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is a formula for cell AI16 to lookup AC14:AF42 for a match of AI14, on match, need to also match adjacent offset -3/3 columns to AH16.  On exact match, pull out the first lookup adjacent cell.

Therefore, cell AI16 should find in AC14:AF42 array a match for "Dart Knights", on match, also find across from the lookeup cell to match "Holydarts".  On both statements being true, post out the adjacent file.

eg. AI16 logical statement AC14:AF42 Dart Knights (cell AF32) true, then AC14:AF42 Holydarts (cell AC32) true, output cell AE32.

I thought about doing 2 separate functions to compare one side only, so I could use the offset.

Answer (score 0):

if you are comfortable with array functions,

```
{=sum(($AC$14:$AC$42 = AI$14)*($AF$14:$AF$42 = $AH16)*($AE$14:$AE$42))}
```

use ctrl+shift+enter to input this function.

Though I don't know if it will work in google sheets.